# How do you switch 2 different Views by using Drag Gesture in Android?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gesture

so im trying to create an interface where the user can drag their finger from the right to the left to get to the second view, and the first view being dragged will move from right to left. very similar to an android device home screen, where the user can drag a screen to the left or right and another screen will emerge from there. I have so far a View switcher where flipper will store two xml files. But i do not know how to use the drag gesture? any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) which u might find usefull..get back to me for any query.

> HorizontalPager for Android
>   HorizontalPager is a modified version
>   of Marc Reichelt's RealViewSwitcher.
>   It's essentially a horizontal
>   ScrollView that snaps to a full-width
>   child (like the Android homescreen's
>   switching behavior). This modified
>   version supports vertically scrolling
>   children

Comment: @user651377 Please add a bit of context to the link so that it doesn't look like spam, and in case the linked page goes down.

Comment: @Blowski, good idea. I took the liberty and added some context as an example to the new user.

Answer (score 0):

I just write one example integrate the drag gesture and image switch effect. Hope it helps.

All the needed resources and code as the following:

1. main layout : add a ImageSwitcher into the layout
2. two drawable named as R.drawable.s3, R.drawable.s4
3. two animation files, slide_right_in, slide_left_out

   ```
       public class PureTestActivity extends Activity{
           final String TAG = PureTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();
           /** Called when the activity is first created. */

           LinearLayout mainLL;
           GestureDetector gestureDetector;
           ImageSwitcher vs;
           int imageIdx = 0;
           int[] imageResId = {R.drawable.s3, R.drawable.s4};
           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.main);


               mainLL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

               vs = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher1);
               vs.setFactory(new ViewFactory(){

           @Override
           public View makeView() {

                 ImageView i = new ImageView(PureTestActivity.this);
                 i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
                 i.setImageResource(R.drawable.s3);
                 i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                 i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                 return i;
           }
       });


       vs.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
               android.R.anim.fade_in));
       vs.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
               android.R.anim.fade_out));
       //start for touch events  Gesture detection
       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
       View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

               Log.d(TAG, "ontouch event.");
               if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
           }
       };
       vs.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
   }     
      class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

           final String TAG = MyGestureDetector.class.getSimpleName();

           // for touch left or touch right events
           private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 60;   //default is 120
           private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
           private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

           @Override
           public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

               Log.d(TAG, " on down events :" + e.getAction() );
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

               Log.d(TAG, " on filing event, first velocityX :" + velocityX +
                       " second velocityY" + velocityY);
               try {
                   if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                       return false;
                   // right to left swipe
                   if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                           onHorizonTouch(true);  // left

                   }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                           onHorizonTouch(false); // right   

                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   // nothing
               }
               return false;
           }

           void onHorizonTouch(Boolean toLeft){
               if(toLeft && imageIdx>0)
               {
                   vs.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                           getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right_in));
                   // 设置切出动画
                   vs.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                           getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_left_out));
                   PureTestActivity.this.vs.setImageResource(imageResId[--imageIdx]);
               }
               if(!toLeft && imageIdx<1)
               {
                   vs.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PureTestActivity.this,
                           android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                   vs.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PureTestActivity.this,
                           android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
                   PureTestActivity.this.vs.setImageResource(imageResId[++imageIdx]);
               }

           };
       }
   ```

   }